# Installing php7 on El Capitan, terminal display version 7 and browser still display 5.5

Tags: php, homebrew, php-7

I'm trying to install php 7 on El Capitan via homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php70
```

Version in terminal display:

```
PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 14 2016 09:55:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

And browser, via phpinfo() still display php 5.5.36.

I commented this line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

And php is just not working at all in browser (display list of files intead of process them) but still output version 7 on terminal.

I'm lost. Somebody may have some action that I can do to diagnosis and fix my issue please? Where should I see?

Thanks

Comment: did you add the php7 module to apache? all you did was disable php5...

Comment: No I didn't. I didn't see it anywhere in the process which line to add and didn't found anything usefull with "locate libphp5.so" or "locate libphp7.so". I feel like somethings missing here. :)

Comment: Very similar, maybe even a duplicate? : [osx php7 apache not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456022/osx-php7-apache-not-working/39561772#39561772)

Comment: not resolved, but it works since I use PHP OSX package instead of Homebrew. Sadly. (https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not resolved, but it works since I use PHP OSX package instead of Homebrew. Sadly. ([jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x))

Thanks

EDIT: I finally resolved with this post: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions and keeping my lovely Homebrew setup. For short: I had to add the "use-apache24-for-installing-php" option. :)

Comment: I am solving similar issue with vagrant