# Apache do not load libphp7.so module

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, php-7.1

I installed **php7.1** using `brew install php71 --with-httpd24` and unlinked httpd24. I got working version of php7.1 together with libphp7.so.
[php7.1 running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Wl0.png)

But when I add `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` to *httpd.conf* file, php files stop working. When I uncommented back `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` everything works fine. Any Idea?

PS.OS Version: 10.12.2

Comment: have you tried to include the other version? LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

Comment: I've got single version of libphp7.so

Comment: checking sudo apachectl configtest works fine

Comment: does it work with which php version? is there the module at /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so?

Comment: configtest works fine with both version and there is the module at /usr/local/opt/php71/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

Answer (score 4):

[Ubuntu 16.04] - Check next file: /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.1.load

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.1.so`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this solved:

```
You've followed the instructions from brew info php@7.1:

==> Caveats
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

You restarted Apache via sudo apachectl restart.
```

You can check de original post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44978996

Answer (score 0):

I've been using system apache and updated php using brew and got stuck there. After I've been following every steps in https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions and shifted to brew apache, it works like a charm.